# Перестали исполняться js файлы на сайте

Tags: jquery, javascript, php, сервер

Здравствуйте. Перестали исполняться js файлы на сайте http://zs-service.ru/ , а именно не запускается форма обратного звонка. Выдаёт ошибку 500. Хотя через исходный код файлы открываются без проблем. Права на папки выставил 755, на файлы 644. Не могу понять в чем проблема, день назад всё работало отлично.

В указанных файлах я никаких изменений не вносил, день назад всё работало нормально. Потом посыпались ошибки, и при обращении к другим js файлам, вылезают ошибки. Возможно-ли что хостер запретил выполнение js на страницах сайта или то что сайт взломали?

**Обновление**

В указанных файлах я никаких изменений не вносил, день назад всё работало нормально. Потом посыпались ошибки, и при обращении к другим js файлам, вылезают ошибки. Возможно-ли что хостер запретил выполнение js на страницах сайта или то что сайт взломали?

Comment: Проверьте, нет ли синтаксической ошибки в файле, что занимается обработкой данных по этому урлу http://zs-service.ru/module/frcallback/actions

Иногда во время синтаксической ошибки (забыли закрыть скобку, например), сервер отдает 500 ошибку. Лучше проверяйте специализированными IDE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) 500 - это не JS, смотрите в логах сервера:

```
the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://zs-service.ru/module/frcallback/actions?process=getForm&token=8685d433f61c420144a5a114c81159c2&ajax=true
```

Может и там подробности всплывут, а может придётся и в обработчик этого action обложить отладочным выводом, вам видней.

2) А вот JS ваш выдаёт следующее:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sfTimer' of undefined superfish-modified.js:95
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sfTimer' of undefined superfish-modified.js:105
```

Но - за вас с этим никто не разберётся, учитесь хотя бы самыми простыми средствами отладки и диагностики пользоваться.

**Обновление**

Хостер не может запретить выполнение JS, они вполняются на клиентской стороне. Ошибка же на сервере, то есть на вашей стороне, значит, не в JS (хотя косвенно может быть связана с JS, например, неправильная обработка каких-то данных, которые приходят от JS). Подробней вам тут никто не скажет - телепатов маловато стало в последнее время :( У вас в руках есть ВСЕ инструменты для поиска ошибки, от серверных логов до исходников движка, воспользуйтесь ими самостоятельно. Или пригласите специалиста, если эти слова вам ни о чём не говорят.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Хостер не может запретить выполнение JS, они вполняются на клиентской стороне. Ошибка же на сервере, то есть на вашей стороне, значит, не в JS (хотя косвенно может быть связана с JS, например, неправильная обработка каких-то данных, которые приходят от JS). Подробней вам тут никто не скажет - телепатов маловато стало в последнее время :( У вас в руках есть ВСЕ инструменты для поиска ошибки, от серверных логов до исходников движка, воспользуйтесь ими самостоятельно. Или пригласите специалиста, если эти слова вам ни о чём не говорят.